# How to read the data from node js post ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, web

I am trying to send a data from client to server (node js) . I am using ajax .

client :

```
$("#test_button").on("click",function(){
    //alert("shit");
    $.ajax(
        {url: "http://localhost:4000/ajax_check", 
        async: false, 
        type: "POST",
        data: "{user:balayya,password:hero}",
        success: function(result){
            alert("hooli");
        }});
});
```

server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http').Server(app);


http.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:4000');
});

app.use(express.static('publuc'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("new entry page serving");
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/main.html');
});

app.post('/ajax_check', function(req, res){
    console.log("someone came in here");
    console.log(req.query.data);
});
```

the console.log() is printing as "undefined" . 
What is the correct way to receive a post request and it's data from the client in node js

Comment: Adding a body-parser to this worked .

Comment: If that is your solution, you should click the checkmark under the answer. It will help others who stumble upon this question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this npm package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

and so server site parse like this:
request.body.{some field name}

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:4000/ajax_check", 
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        user: "balayya",
        password: "hero"
    },
    success: function(result) {
        alert("hooli");
    }
});
```

And on the server use `req.body.param_name` to read the corresponding parameter value:

```
app.post('/ajax_check', function(req, res){
    console.log("someone came in here");
    console.log(req.body.user);
    console.log(req.body.password);
});
```

Also notice that I have removed `async: false` from your AJAX request because every time someone sets this property to `false` a poor kitten dies.

Comment: Adding a body-parser to this worked . Thanks . I am not going to kill a poor kitten , I promise.